# Element sided to another instead of below it

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

This is a CSS issue: i have a drop down menu created with the following code:

```
   #menu_container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline;
}

#menu_container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#menu_container ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#menu_container ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menu_container ul li.current-menu-item a, #menu_container ul li.current_page_item a  {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menu_container ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#menu_container ul li ul li a { 
  display: block; 
}

#menu_container ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menu_container ul li ul li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;;
}

#menu_container {
  border-top: 1px dotted #DDDDDD;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #DDDDDD;
  padding: 0px 28px;
}

#menu_container .cat_menu { border-left: 1px dotted #DDDDDD; }
```

The site is [edicionesparalelo.com](http://edicionesparalelo.com)

As you can see if you access it, when you hover over "Blog" the elements i want to display DO display, but not is i want. I want them to display one below the other. I mean:

Reseñas
Textos

And not like they appear:

Reseñas Textos

I will really thank any help; this is driving me mad. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you have "display: inline;" in there, that will put things beside each other inside the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers above are almost there.

I got it to work with this in my Google Dev tools. It's best not to use !important, so try removing them after you verified this works:

```
sub-menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display: block !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the problematic elements and solve the issue by doing something like this:

```
   #menu_container ul li ul {
    width: 70px; /** desired_width **/
    }



 #menu_container ul li ul li {
    width: 100%; /** 100% width makes them stack on each other and not side by side **/
    display: block
    }
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new rule to `.sub-menu`:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove that float and that display:inline-block from your elements.

For example:

```
.sub-menu > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
```

Once this is applied your list items will break into new lines again.

And by the way:
Your defintion of

```
#menu_container ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

is quite general. This is the source of your problem. It matches too many li elements.